# Error con procedimiento almacenado "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified" con LinQ y C#

Tags: c#, sql, linq, stored-procedure, linq-to-sql

estoy recibiendo el mensaje de error "Procedure or function has too many arguments specified" al tratar de utilizar un procedimiento almacenado. El mensaje es bastante especifico, pero no logro identificar el error pues el sp en cuestión **recibe 8 parámetros y yo le estoy enviando 8 parámetros**. He revisado foros y preguntas, pero todos parecen indicar revisar solamente el # de inputs que recibe el sp.

El sp:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_createParam]
 @param1 NUMERIC(18,0)
,@param2 VARCHAR(20)
,@param3 INT
,@param4 INT
,@param5 VARCHAR(16)
,@param6 VARCHAR(50)
,@param7 VARCHAR(100)
,@param8 NUMERIC(10,0)

AS
BEGIN
    
INSERT INTO [Params]
(param1
,param2
,param3
,param4
,param5
,param6
,param7
,param_creationDate
,param8
)
VALUES
(@param1
,@param2
,@param3
,@param4
,@param5
,@param6
,@param7
,GETDATE()
,@param8
)
RETURN SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Y el método:

```
public CreateParamsOut CreateParams(CreateParamsIn input)
    {
        CreateParamsOut output = new CreateParamsOut () { result = Entities.Common.Result.Error };
        using (var dataContext = DataContextHelper.GetDataContext<ApplicantDataContext>()
        {
            var linqResult = dataContext.sp_createParam(input.param1,
                                                            input.param2,
                                                            input.param3,
                                                            input.param4,
                                                            input.param5,
                                                            input.param6,
                                                            input.param7,
                                                            input.param8);
            if (linqResult > 0)
            {
                //Success;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

**He revisado y el apuntamiento a la BD está bien**, incluso realicé un profiler y en la traza se evidencia que los parámetros están llegando bien. Los campos también existen en la tabla en cuestión.

```
declare @p11 int
set @p11=NULL
exec sp_executesql N'EXEC @RETURN_VALUE = [dbo].[sp_createParam] @param1 = @p0, @param2 = @p1, 
@param3= @p2, @param4= @p3, @param5= @p4, @param6= @p5, 
@param7= @p6, @param8= @p7',N'@p0 decimal(18,0),@p1 varchar(8000),@p2 int,@p3 int,@p4 
varchar(8000),@p5 varchar(8000),@p6 varchar(8000),@p7 decimal(10,0),@RETURN_VALUE int output',@p0=12, 
@p1='string1', @p2=1, @p3=2, @p4='string2', @p5='1', 
@p6='string3', @p7=1234567890, @RETURN_VALUE=@p11 output
select @p11
```

Al parecer todo está en orden en cuento a número de parámetros enviados y los que recibe el sp. ¿Algún consejo respecto a qué más debería revisar? Agradezco cualquier guía al respecto.

Comment: Yo lo veo correcto, yo revisaría el valor de los parámetros, no sea que por un `null` el compilador se equivoque y de un mensaje de error equívoco.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario. Realicé un debug y veo que todos los inputs están entrando con un valor, lo mismo se ve en la traza que muestro en la pregunta (Todos los parámetros desde @ p0 a @ p7 muestran su valor). Es muy extraño, no logro identificar el problema.